# Drop columns from table using option CHECKPOINT

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ddl

Need to drop 3 columns from table having about 3 million rows.  It is taking about 3 hours to drop 3 columns.  I'm thinking of using CHECKPOINT but not sure if what CHECKPOINT number I need to use. Also is it safe to use CHECKPOINT option?

We are on Oracle 12.2

So far, I've tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table1> SET UNUSED (<col1>, <col2>, <col3>);

ALTER TABLE <table1> DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to improve performance, or to conserve UNDO space used?

`CHECKPOINT` will not improve performance. Your command must alter all 3 million rows of data, regardless. `CHECKPOINT` will limit the amount of UNDO rows that exist at any one time, but it won't limit the total number of UNDO rows that need to be created over the course of the transaction. If anything, checkpointing - which will clear UNDO records and write more to REDO - will introduce *even more* disk I/O operations to your transaction and slow it down further.

`CHECKPOINT` is really only useful if you have limited disk capacity for your UNDO tablespace, in which case the number of rows should depend on the amount of UNDO space used per row and the total amount of space you can allow for the transaction. That may take experimentation to determine - start high and work down until the transaction completes - you want was few checkpoints as possible while staying within your UNDO storage threshhold.

Also, per the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877) anything that goes wrong after a checkpoint has been applied and before the transaction is complete may leave the table in an unstable/unusable state. Therefore it is not *entirely* safe. Use with caution, and be prepared to restore from backup if things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one off operation, just re-create the table without the columns.